# Azure WebJob Best Approach

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

This is my first time that I've done a WebJob Type of application. I have created a webjob project and in the solution it comes with `Program.cs` and `Function.cs`.

I have already removed `Function.cs` because in this project there is no queue I will be getting data from.

Now in `Program.cs` there is already Main Method as the following:

```
class Program
{
    // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
    // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
    static void Main()
    {
        var host = new JobHost();
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

As I understand, that `RunAndBlock` is to run the webjob continuously, but I want the job to run one time only. I want to control the execution from outside by a schedule. I would like to know how to make my code run only one time?
As seen below, I have a `SupportService` Class that has `RunOnePoolProvisioingCycle`, I want to call this method one time only.
Is this the right approach?

```
static void Main()
{
    SupportService _supportService = new SupportService();
    _supportService.Initialize();
    _supportService.SetPoolProvisioningConfigurations();
    _supportService.RunOnePoolProvisioningCycle();
}
```

or this one?

```
static void Main()
{
    var host = new JobHost();
    SupportService _supportService = new SupportService();
    _supportService.Initialize();
    _supportService.SetPoolProvisioningConfigurations();
    host.Call(typeof(SupportService).GetMethod("SetPoolProvisioningConfigurations"));
}
```

or this one?

```
static void Main()
{
    var host = new JobHost();
    SupportService _supportService = new SupportService();
    _supportService.Initialize();
    _supportService.SetPoolProvisioningConfigurations();
    host.CallAsync(typeof(SupportService).GetMethod("SetPoolProvisioningConfigurations"));
}
```

or should I use:

```
host.Start()
```

or

```
host.StartAsync()?
```

Comment: I believe all answers here are correct, as my question is about approach. but i have to select one.

this note for any one who is seeing this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is part of the SDK, which is optional.
A webjob can be as simple as a console Application that you Zip, upload and run as is.

So this code seems the best option in your case:

```
static void Main()
{
    SupportService _supportService = new SupportService();
    _supportService.Initialize();
    _supportService.SetPoolProvisioningConfigurations();
    _supportService.RunOnePoolProvisioningCycle();
}
```

Comment: so it will be the first code, that call the supportservice directly.
but i have read the SDK provided in MSDN, and I really could not understand anything from it. do you recommend any documentation for the JobHost Class and Properties and functions. and when i should use everyone of them, and what is the best practice of each?

Comment: Yes I would use the first code you propose.The SDK does a great job in exposing Azure storage as a set of triggers and streams; in that case, the host has the role of the "infinite loop".

Answer (score 1):

The WebJob created by the template uses the [WebJobs SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources). If you don't need to use any of the features of the SDK, then you can just create a console app and set up a **CRON schedule** to run it on (see "Scheduled jobs" [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs)).

I linked to more information on the WebJobs SDK above. In addition to facilitating scenarios where you want to trigger functions on queues/blobs/etc., it also has the ability to run your jobs on schedule via **TimerTrigger** (part of the [SDK extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions)). Give those materials a read to see which suits your needs the best.